# How to add shadow to fixed column and fixed row using the UICollectionViewLayout for presenting the tabular data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want shadow to be there on first fixed column and first fixed row only and when I do scrolling horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0{
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                cell.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileImageView.frame.width/2
                cell.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
                cell.profileImageView.clipsToBounds = true
                
                cell.previewView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                cell.previewImageBgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                cell.previewBgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                
                cell.previewBgView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
                cell.previewBgView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(r: 234/255, g: 234/255, b: 234/255).cgColor
                cell.previewBgView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5, height: 5)
            }
        }
```

Comment: use Bool variable Flag ,  scrollview delegate called enable flag true 

if (flag ){ } add that code inside flag condition

Comment: above code add cellrow